# Use `Application.FindFormat` to find all the other different format (Color)?

Tags: excel, vba, format

I am using the below code to select the colored cells (Yellow) on usedrange.
In the same sheet I have other cells filled with another different colors.
I am asking, is it possible to use `Application.FindFormat` to find all the other different format (Color)?
I tried to use :

```
Application.FindFormat.Interior.Color <> vbYellow
```

But I got syntax error. In advance, grateful for all your help.

```
Sub Answer()
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Dim crg As Range
    Set crg = ws.UsedRange
 
  Application.FindFormat.Interior.Color = vbYellow
 
    Dim rg As Range, c As Variant, FirstAddress As Variant
    Set c = crg.Find(What:=vbNullString, SearchFormat:=True)
 
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        FirstAddress = c.Address
            Do
                If rg Is Nothing Then
                   Set rg = c
                 Else
                   Set rg = Union(rg, c)
                End If
                Set c = crg.Find(What:=vbNullString, after:=c, SearchFormat:=True)
            Loop While c.Address <> FirstAddress
        rg.Select
    Else
        MsgBox "no cell with yellow color found"
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Application.FindFormat` in Excel/VBA can do exactly the same as the Find-Dialog in Excel. As you can see, there is no "not equal" search in Excel for formatting, so there is no such search in VBA.

To get a list of colors and it's usage, you will have to loop over all cells. The following code builds a dictionary of colors and it's usage and dumps the result to the immediate window. Call it for example with `ListAllColors ws.UsedRange`

```
Sub ListAllColors(r As Range)
    Dim colorList As Object
    Set colorList = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In r
        Dim color
        If cell.Interior.ColorIndex <> xlNone Then
            color = cell.Interior.color
            If colorList.exists(color) Then
                ' Color already in List, add cell to Range
                Dim colorRange As Range
                Set colorRange = colorList(color)
                Set colorList(color) = Union(colorRange, cell)
            Else
                ' New color, add entry to Dict
                colorList.Add color, ""
                ' Ensure that the content is set to the cell itself, not the value.
                Set colorList(color) = cell
            End If
        End If
    Next
  
    ' Dump the result  
    For Each color In colorList.keys
        Dim red As Long, green As Long, blue As Long
        Call getRGB(CLng(color), red, green, blue)
        Debug.Print color, "R:" & red, "G:" & green, "B:" & blue, colorList(color).Address
    Next
End Sub

' Split color into it's red, green and blue parts
Public Sub getRGB(color As Long, ByRef red As Long, ByRef green As Long, ByRef blue As Long)
    red = color And vbRed
    green = (color And vbGreen) \ &H100
    blue = (color And vbBlue) \ &H10000
End Sub
```

**Update**
To get a range of *all* colored cells, you can simplify the code, you will still have to loop over all cells, but can immediately build the union.   Have a look to the following function. I added an optional parameter so you can ignore all cells with a certain color (eg vbYellow).

```
Function GetColoredCells(r As Range, Optional IgnoreColor As Long = -1) As Range
    
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In r
        Dim color
        If cell.Interior.ColorIndex <> xlNone And cell.Interior.color <> IgnoreColor Then
            If GetColoredCells Is Nothing Then
                Set GetColoredCells = cell
            Else
                Set GetColoredCells = Union(GetColoredCells, cell)
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

To omit the first line, call the function for example like that:

```
Set rg = GetColoredCells(ws.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0), vbYellow)
```

Comment: Your answer can not run as a `Sub` , anyhow I changed it to function.
Actually, **my aim** is to put all the colored cells (except first row) into variable as range.

Comment: I updates my answer, have a look

Comment: Note: `Optional IgnoreColor` has no effect at all , `vbYellow` still added to the range `rg`

Comment: Your are right with the IgnoreColor, corrected.